# Sniping places in Berlin?

Tags: pc, tanki-online

Berlin has taken TDM by storm these days, and I see it frequently. Can someone please post where are the best shaft sniping places there? I am a M0 shaft that uses a M0 Viking and an M1 Mammoth, but mostly the viking in Berlin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay - another Tanker!

Outlined in the picture below are three of my favorite sniping spots.

[image: Berlin - Tanki Online]

Hope this helps!

<sub>Map gotten from [Tanki Fourm](http://en.tankiforum.com/index.php?showtopic=177152)</sub>

Comment: Sorry - didn't realize how old this was!

Comment: Where did you find the map?

Comment: There's a small link at the bottom of me answer - here it is again: http://en.tankiforum.com/index.php?showtopic=177152